# Django how to get the id of already created item in file rename

Tags: python, django

```
def file_directory_path(instance, filename):
    filename_tr = filename
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    filename_tr = str(instance.pk) + "_" + name + ext

    return 'files/%s' % (filename_tr)
```

here the `instance.pk` is set to `None` when a the model object is not yet created, is there a way to somehow get the id after it is created? or the only way is to rename it again in the `save_model` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want get instance id after creating object you can use post_save signal in django for your func. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save